# How to be able to click on a TR and edit personalia

Tags: javascript, function

I'm studying webdevelopment and I'm doing a single page application right now. We are using JavaScript, and I can`t use jquery, bootstrap, etc. I have googled, seen the videos from the lectures, but I am still blank as a canvas.

The problem is I need to make a contactregistre. You should be able to click on the contacts, a different section of the page should be made active where you will be able to edit the contacts and see where they live. The map is OK, but I don`t know how I can make this happen, I find no examples about this which does not suggest using jquery.

We have guessed something like this, but it is probably wrong:

```
document.querySelector("tr").addEventListener('click' , e => {
    document.querySelector('editContact')

    function editContact(contact) {
        let editContact = document.querySelector("#searchcontact tr");
        editContact.innerHTML = "TR";
        let form = document.editContact()
    }
})
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Did you study how to debug your JavaScript. Start [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp) for example. In order to be compete you should also add your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to do this. This is not a complete solution, but should get you started:

Typically you'd have a text input already in your table `<input name="username_1" class="hidden" type="text">`, which is hidden, along side the content, like `<span id="username_1">MAREN</span>`

Then you'd have some CSS to hid things:

```
.hidden {
   display:none;
}
```

So on the click even you'd add the *hidden* classname to the SPAN and remove it from the INPUT. This visually swaps the static value for the label.

There's more to it after that, but give it a try.